# Laravel 5.3 wont connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I created a new user on my Macbook Air (OS X Version 10.11.2). The new  user has full administrator access. I'm using MAMP. The MySQL port is set to 3306. I can connect to MySQL with everything else just fine. All of my Laravel projects stopped connecting to MySQL. When i try to use

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get:

```
[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Here is the database portion of my .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=store
DB_USERNAME=clerk
DB_PASSWORD=inventory
```

I have tried using the root user and password.  I have tried using different ports. I have tried switching the host to localhost. I have verified that the username and password are correct, and that the user has access to the database.
Here is the MySQL portion of my config/database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'store'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'clerk'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'inventory'),
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix' => '',
  'strict' => true,
  'engine' => null,
],
```

I have been searching for a few days, and i can't seem to find the answer. My old Laravel 5.2 projects won't connect either.  I'm pretty sure that this was caused by creating a new user, but i don't know enough about MySQL to figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you connect with the `mysql` command line tool or the MySQL Workbench program or equivalent? Have you tried using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @tadman | I answered both of those questions in the original post.

Comment: connection refused means mysql isn't running, or isn't listening. which means that the user/pass are irrelevant at this stage. you're not even getting a connection to mysql to TRY and log in with. if it was a permissions thing, you'd get "access denied"

Comment: Do set `'strict' => false,` instead of `'strict' => true,` and run a connection test. Also, your *default* connection string should be set to *MySQL* as in: `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')` in your `config/database.php` file.

Comment: @Marc B | MySQL is running. I can connect with all other programs that use MySQL as well as through the terminal

Comment: @nyedidikeke I set 'strict' => false and nothing changed.  The config/database.php file has 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql').

Comment: Did you check the laravel created log? Also try creating a simple php script using PDO  outside laravel and see if you can connect.

Comment: @winteck Yes.  [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f50177558f90e305a2c322f1bc5c0312)

Comment: Set `'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'localhost')`. *Your error log points to your port anyway*.

Comment: Do run ***php artisan config:clear*** then ***php artisan migrate*** afterwards. What's the result?

Comment: @nyedidikeke I tried that, but the problem still persists. Nothing changes in the laravel.log file. Also tried clearing the configuration cache and nothing changed.

Comment: Do set `DB_HOST` to `localhost` as well in your `.env` file and follow the process above. Should that fail, set your *MySQL* port to **33060**, then,  `'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'localhost:33060')` and `DB_HOST=localhost:33060`, with the same process above (***php artisan config:clear*** then ***php artisan migrate***).

Comment: @nyedidikeke Tried that.  It returned with **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory**

Comment: Are you running your Laravel installation on a Virtual Machine?

Comment: @nyedidikeke no. Like i mentioned in the original question, Macbook Air OS X Version 10.11.2 El Capitan

Comment: Wow ... brainstorming further.

Comment: @nyedidikeke Just logged into the old user.  Same problem there.

Comment: Currently installing Laravel 5.3 so as to look closely.

Comment: Everything is working fine! You must be missing something. I suggest you [export your database](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/import-export-mysql-database-command-line/), uninstall your MySQL, then download a new one at [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Follow the approach elaborated [here](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/#mysql) for a possible fix *(a PATH issue I now presume)*. Do remember to update the community of the outcome afterward.

Comment: @nyedidikeke thanks for the help. I'll update tomorrow probably.

Comment: Sure; will be on the look out for your update.

Comment: After creation of a new user did you grant all privileges to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having followed troubleshooting processes as I've suggested in comments below your question, all should be working as expected.

Should that not be the case, you must be missing something; ... a PATH issue I presume.

I suggest you [export your database](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/import-export-mysql-database-command-line/), uninstall your MySQL, then download a new one at [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

Follow the approach elaborated [here](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/#mysql) for a possible fix.

With this, your challenge will surely be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your db_host = localhost:3306

Answer (score 0):

You define an `engine = null`. The engine is used inside the `MySqlGrammar.php` specifically when compiling a create query as far as I know. I have only seen null engines for VIEWS.

Try the following config:

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'store'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'clerk'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'inventory'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

You did mention it in your question and take it that the following works from a terminal

```
mysql -uclerk -pinventory -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 store
```

Could be that it needs to be

```
mysql -uclerk -pinventory -hlocalhost -P3306 store
```

Something else you can check with just an `info.php` file in your project to double check that everything seems fine with the reference to PDO as a module.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then also play around with just a little PDO php script to see if your connection is working properly. Something like:

```php
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "clerk";
$password = "inventory";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=3306;dbname=store;", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Something else you can also check inside a dummy route what `env('DB_DATABASE')` etc gives you.

**Updated things to check 2016.09.15**

To make sure that `env()` is fetching the correct information include the route below and then include the output of the following:

```php
Route::get('dbtest', function () {
    $config = [
        'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    ];
    dd($config);
});
```

Then also access `mysql` as the root user and include the output of the select statement:

```
mysql> select host, user, password, authentication_string, password_expired from mysql.user;
```

As you are using MAMP make sure to use the mysql commandline tool from `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql`

Comment: Tried what you suggested: mysql -uclerk -pinventory -hlocalhost -P3306 store worked fine.  The PDO script worked perfectly fine also.

Comment: If -hlocalhost worked then you would need to update your DB_HOST in your .env file from 127.0.0.1 to localhost. I added two other things you can check.

Answer (score 0):

It's been solved.  After a few hours of pulling my hair out, i decided to take @nyedidikeke advice and re-install mysql.  I was using MAMP, and I have been wanting to stop using it for a while.  I uninstalled it, and installed mysql through Homebrew.  Everything is working just fine, thanks for all your help!